# WebTest Project in Visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, web-testing

I have been reading the documentation on WebTet and LoadTest projects and visual studio and at the time of creating the project in visual studio 2017 Prfessional I discovered that the template does not exist.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2017

inquiring I discovered that it only exists for the enterprise version.
Is there a similar type of project or extension that I can use in the same way for Professional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Web and Load test types and projects are only available in the Enterprise version. See (and expand) the "Testing tools" section of the [Visual Studio version comparisons](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) page.

Comment: Then there is no other similar alternative? Not necessarily included in visual studio either

Comment: @Jsanchez Asking for other software recommendations is off-topic here. Please read the [help] pages about how to write a good question.